# Updated to latest version of VirtualBox but unable to run any of my machines

Tags: virtualbox

I am currently running VirtualBox version 5.1.30 on a thinkpad laptop with Ubuntu version 17.10. I have tried to update to the latest VirtualBox however my machines fail to work properly on the latest version. I am using VB to run Whonix. I am hoping somebody can help me out. Photos of the errors that I am receiving are below. Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DMIe.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bz0Z.jpg

Comment: Did you `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`, as VirtualBox asked you?